# Cargar eventos en fullcalendar v4 ajax Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, ajax, json, array, fullcalendar

Tengo un problema con fullcalendar v4, intento cargar los datos mediante ajax, pero no se muestran los eventos y no me lanza ningún error.

en la v3 de fullcalendar no tenia problemas, pero en la v4 no puedo lograr hacerlo.

en la función de mi controlador creo un array con los datos necesarios para cargar los eventos.

los eventos los envió a la base de datos con el formato que proporciona carbón `toIso8601String`

Codigo de fullcalendar script

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');  
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid', 'interaction', 'list' ],
            height: 800,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,today,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listMonth'
            },
            buttonText: {
                today: 'Hoy',
                month: 'Mes',
                agendaWeek: 'Semana',
                agendaDay: 'Dia'
            },
            axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            editable: false,
            droppable: false,
            eventTextColor:"#FFF",
            eventColor:"#337AB7",
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            eventLimit: 4,
            eventDurationEditable: false,
            locale: 'es',
            timeZone: 'UTC -4',
            themeSystem: 'themeSystem',
            defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
            nowIndicator: true,
            eventsSources: 
                function ( start, end, timeZoneStr, callback ){
                    $.ajax({
                      type:'GET',
                      url:'{{ url("load_calendar" )}}',
                      success: function (data){
                        callback(data);
                      }
                    })
                  }
        })
        calendar.render();
});
</script>
```

esta es la funcion de mi controlador

```
public function load_calendar(){

    $all_event = calendarModel::all()->toArray();


    $event_data=array();

    foreach ($all_event as $key => $event_val) {

        $event_data[$key]['title'] =$event_val['event_titulo'];
        $event_data[$key]['start'] =date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($event_val['event_fecha_inicio']));
        $event_data[$key]['end']  =date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($event_val['event_fecha_final']));

        $event_data[$key]['start_formate'] =date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($event_val['event_fecha_inicio']));
        $event_data[$key]['end_formate']  =date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($event_val['event_fecha_final']));


        $event_data[$key]['events_id'] = $event_val['id'];
        $event_data[$key]['event_description'] =$event_val['event_descripcion'];
        $event_data[$key]['created_at'] =date('d/m/Y', strtotime($event_val['created_at']));
        $event_data[$key]['updated_at'] =date('d/m/Y', strtotime($event_val['updated_at']));

    } 

        echo json_encode($event_data);
        dump($event_data);

    }
```

mi ruta es la siguiente

`Route::get('load_calendar','calendarController@load_calendar')->name('load_calendar');`

Este es lo que devuelve el array del json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas lineas son de prueba? :`echo json_encode($event_data);dump($event_data);`

Comment: @Shassain si, el echo era para poder visualizar de forma directa la ruta (esta en return actualmente) y el dump para visualizar la carga de los arrays en el dump-server como lo muestra la imagen que adjunte a la pregunta

Comment: @KilzaNiko no es correcto que pongas SOLUCIONADO al título de tu pregunta y que ahi mismo publiques la respuesta, si ya marcaste una solución como aceptada con eso alcanza. y en caso de que la solución sea la tuya entonces publicala en la zona de respuestas (y no olvides marcar como ACEPTADA la que resolvió tu problema)

Comment: Aaaaa vale, lo edito de inmediato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eventsSources` no existe, es `eventSources`.

Si lo que querés es mostrar los eventos que obtenés por JSON, usá [events (as a json feed)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) . Reemplazá tu `eventsSources` por `events`.

```
events: '{{ url("load_calendar" )}}'
```

Por otro lado, el formato de las fechas de `start` y `end` no es correcto. Tenés que utilizar alguna de las definidas en [Date Parsing](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing):

```
$event_data[$key]['start'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($event_val['event_fecha_inicio']));
$event_data[$key]['end']  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($event_val['event_fecha_final']));
```

Por último, como bien dice @Shassain, si querés especificar que querés devolver un JSON usá la sintaxis de Laravel:

```
return response()->json($event_data);
```

Sino con devolver directamente el `array` es suficiente, Laravel lo convierte automáticamente en JSON.

```
return $event_data;
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @azeós, hice los cambios que me indicaste y ahora si me indica un error `Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function` el cual hace referencia a la linea `callback(data);`, tenia entendido que ese error lo generaba la funcion `function ( start, end, timeZoneStr, callback )`, tambien probe con timezone y con no incluirla, al igual que con startStr y endStr, pero aun asi me aparece dicho error

Comment: No tendrías que tener eso, solo la línea que te pasé. Actualizá tu pregunta y pone el nuevo código.

Comment: Esta actualizado ahora

Comment: @KilzaNiko borrá toda la función que tenés dentro de `events`. Solo poné la URL como te puse más arriba. Con eso solo tiene que ser suficiente.

Comment: lo intente y el calendario carga, pero los eventos no, al igual que en un principio

Comment: @KilzaNiko Desde el explorador revisá la solapa network/red y fijate que está devolviendo tu controlador. Para ver si efectivamente está devolviendo un objeto JSON con los eventos.

Comment: lo unico que encontre relacionado con la carga del calendario es esto
https://imgur.com/a/ffVvruG

Comment: @KilzaNiko tiene que ser eso. Hacé click y te tiene que abrir una ventana donde está la "respuesta" del server. Ahí vas a ver exactamente que está devolviendo.

Comment: esto es lo que me devuelve https://imgur.com/a/2EsqYkT

Comment: @KilzaNiko No tendrá que ver con el formato de las fechas `start` y `end`? Probá desde PHP formatearlas como `Y-m-d H:i:s`. La consola no te muestra ningún error?

Comment: probe con ese formato en mi controlador y efectivamente funciono!, muchas gracias por la ayuda y por la paciencia!
https://imgur.com/LPB59gx

Comment: @KilzaNiko excelente, ahora actualizo la respuesta para incluir esa modificación así la podes marcar como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

El unico error que veo son las lineas:

```
echo json_encode($event_data);
dump($event_data);
```

El `dump($event_data);` debería de ser borrada. Y de preferencia cambiar el modo de retorno de `echo` a `return`

```
return response()->json($event_data);
```

Comment: igual había intentado con el return, el dump lo use para verificar que el json me entregaba el array de forma correcta (lo cual si esta correcto) y también probé borrando el dump y con return, pero aun así no me indica ningun error y no carga ningún evento

adjuntare una imagen con el tipo de array que devuelve el dump, quizas tenga algo malo